# UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath Returns Wrong Row Index (iOS7)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7

I have a class as "`myUIImage`" extended from `UIScrollView`. it has a `UIImageView` variable.
`ViewController` delegates "`UITableViewDataSource` , `UITableViewDelegate`".

when I add a `myUIImage` object into all cells in `cellforRowAtIndexPath` function,(With a `cellview` that fills whole cell(frame size are same)), the problem occurs.

When i touch one of the rows didSelectRowAtIndexpath returns wrong row index on iOS7. it works well older versions.

I put the example xCode Project here ;
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ps7cc8l51v0grxb/repeatboxDeneme.zip

Thanks For Your Help...

Edit1:

Here is a sample video. Please watch carefully the Logs on down-right side.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5f8-nrlWCIY&feature=youtu.be

Comment: In iOS 7 also returning correct index only....What is your problem on this code???

Comment: If you create a custom Cell, you should create a new class and nib-file just for the cell. This way you can also set an identifier for your sell and your tableView won't get too lazy if you also add any images. Have a look at this tutorial http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/. But it doesn't look like there is something going wrong. I alsways get the right row.

Comment: Erik Please touch one of the rows upside and then scroll the tableview and touch one of the downside 17-19 rows. and just watch the logs. first time you touch you can see the wrong value when you watch carefully.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue you describe - things seem to be working fine.

Comment: i think i should add a video :)

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5f8-nrlWCIY&feature=youtu.be

Comment: This issue only occurs in the iPad simulator - this is important to mention. I think it may be a bug, as the issue does not occur in the iPhone simulator. Perhaps it would be worth running your code on an actual iPad device to determine if it is a simulator issue?

Comment: It occurs on an actual device too Craig. Idk what should I do :/

Answer (score 1):

This is working perfect on both iOS 6 and iOS7 because i've seen your code. And your code is also perfect. But there is a problem that is you are not using reusable cell. So might be it create problem releated to memory and its not a good practice.

Comment: Everything is too complicated. TableView can be inserted inside the storyboard so you can work with the settings inside the interfacebuilder. Own cells so you can set all elements to the right position. Own identifier....

Comment: I don't see how this would create a big problem in the future. Reusable cells exist for performance reasons, but they're certainly not required. While it would be worthwhile for the OP to use reusable cells to ensure he's not recreating cells, and I agree that recreating cells is bad practice, it won't cause any serious problems or bugs.

Comment: @CraigOtis I mean it will create problem related to memory.I think that might be a big problem. And you also know its not a good practice in programming. Because we need to use minimum resources as possbile as.

Comment: Guys this is just a test project that i created to show you the case :)

Answer (score 0):

This is no normal behaviour of `UITableView`. But it looks to me like it just happens if you clicked while scrolling and if it stops it remembers your last click position.
I would recommend you, to insert an `UITableView` into to your view inside the `Storyboard`. Connect the `Delegate` and `Datasource` of your `UITableView` with the `Filesowner` and than just use the methods

```
numberOfSectionsInTableView 
numberOfRowsInSection 
cellForRowAtIndexPath
didSelectRowAtIndexPath
```

Maybe the way you generate your tableview programmatically, there are any attributes missing. The other way you just can look at the `InterfaceBuilder` settings on the right and can change the settings much easier.